# Why does passing a KinectJS object from Client to NodeJS through a function cause loss of class?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using KinectJS to create a Kinect.Rect object.  I'm trying to pass this object from the client to the server.   On the client side (just before passing as an argument the output of the object in console is:

```
box_284
Kinetic.Rect
alpha: 1
centerOffset: Object
className: "Shape"
drag: Object
drawFunc: function (){
eventListeners: Object
fill: "00D2FF"
height: 25
isListening: true
name: undefined
rotation: 0
scale: Object
stroke: "black"
strokeWidth: 4
visible: true
width: 25
x: 100
y: 100
__proto__: Object
```

After send it is:

```
box
Object
alpha: 1
centerOffset: Object
className: "Shape"
drag: Object
eventListeners: Object
fill: "00D2FF"
height: 25
isListening: true
rotation: 0
scale: Object
stroke: "black"
strokeWidth: 4
visible: true
width: 25
x: 100
y: 100
__proto__: Object
```

The KinectJS library is available to the client, is this an issue of 'deep cloning' and how objects get passed?  Is it a problem of not having the library available to the server?  Not sure what to think of this.. fairly new to Javascript.

===============

## Update

I'm sending the argument as follows:

```
socket.emit('add_box', eval("box_" + id));
```

Where the object is something like: box_523

Comment: how do you send it? JSON serialisation doesn't include class information.

Comment: I updated my question with that information.. perhaps is there another way that I should be trying to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'd recommend you have your objects accessible through an array or dictionary of some sort instead of using `eval("box_" + id)`. Putting aside any potential security concerns, indexing into an array will give you much better performance than `eval`.

To get to the heart of your question, the issue is that `socket.emit` serializes and transfers data. Since `drawFunc` is a function and not data, it does not get transferred.

If you think about it, this is fairly straightforward behavior. What would the expected behavior be if you moved a function across the wire? Where would it execute? Would you transfer the actual JavaScript and then eval it on the server?

While these are all questions you could potentially answer and develop your own solution for, it's not something that's available out of the box anywhere.

---

That said, you might want to look into [function calling with nowjs](http://nowjs.com/doc/functions). It might fit your requirements. But again, it doesn't transfer any code across the wire:

> Note: Code is only ever executed on the side on which it is created,
>   this means the body of the function isn't actually being transferred
>   from client to server or server to client, rather there is just a shim
>   for the remote function call when it is synced. This is hugely
>   important for security as it means there is never arbitrary code
>   execution in NowJS

Comment: Thanks Rohan, can you give me a quick example of how I might use an array or a dictionary to accomplish what eval('box_' + id) would?

Comment: I'm not familiar with KinectJS, but here's the general principle. Initialize an array, `boxes = []`. Then every time you create a box, do `boxes.push[myNewBox]`. You should then be able to access any box using, for example, `box[123]`.